# java.lang.NullPointerException:null at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataProperties$Activate.access$100(ConfigDataProperties.java:140)

Tags: spring-boot

I have upgraded spring boot version from 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.6.6. I am getting following error when I start the application.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataProperties$Activate.access$100(ConfigDataProperties.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataProperties.withLegacyProfiles(ConfigDataProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataProperties.get(ConfigDataProperties.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributor.withBoundProperties(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributor.java:241) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:232) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:297) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
```

Comment: Difficult to help without more details. Best if you can provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or at least application properties, pom/gradle, and how you run the application.

Comment: Thank you Samabcde. I found the solution. This problem is happening because of "spring.profiles".  I just commented this property in application.properties file and pass this from VM argument. it worked. This is not available on internet.